# Rudin Problem 9.9 - a mapping of a connected open set in a real valued Euclidean space is constant if $f'(x)=0$ everywhere

Tags: analysis

If $f $ is a differentiable mapping of a connected open set $E \subset \Bbb R^{n} $ into $\Bbb R^{m} $, and if $f'(x) = 0$ for every $x \in E $, prove that $f $ is constant in $E $

Here $f $ is a multivalued function, not sure how to make it bold or with an arrow in MathJax

I have a solution trying to show each partial derivative is 0 and that the values of $f(x)$ are all the same, but it's not eloquent.